# Domain Name Transfer: How to?

Tags: dns, transfer

I don't know anything about it, so I have to ask ...

I have a domain name registered with dotster: MyOld.com
Maybe I will get a new domain name: MyNew.com

The search engine rating is quite high, so I don't want to loose MyOld.com. Right now it is pointing to my old shared webhost. But I found a new webhost. What do I have to do?

1. Change to settings in dotster to point to the new host? Of course I will have to inform my new webhost, too.
2. If I keep the pages, description and keyword the same, the search engine should not have too much of a problem. Right?
3. Is it possible to point two domain names to the same IP? MyOld.com and MyNew.com to the same new webhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This depends on your webhost. Many have a DNS service that will set the authoritative web servers for you. Otherwise you can just set the CNAME on the domain to that of your new webhost.
2. Changing the underlying host should have no discernable impact on your search engine rank,etc.
3. Yes! Absolutely.

Comment: 1. So if the new server has a nameserver, I have to change those settings and that's all I have to do at dotsters, I assume. What is CNAME?

Comment: If your host has their own nameservers then yes that is all you need to do. A CNAME is an alias. Basically a pointer to an ip address